# Changing Breaks on Y Axis in R (Time series)

Tags: r, time-series

I've a dataset showing house prices for a variety of different cities over a period of 19 years, here's what it looks like.

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfKRz.png)

I'm trying to create a time series plot for this data, this is my code so far

```
    Prices <- read.csv("Second Hand Appartment Prices.csv", header=TRUE, skip = 1)
colnames(Prices)[colnames(Prices)=="X"] <- "Year"



National <- ts(Prices$National, start = 1997)
Dublin <- ts(Prices$Dublin, start = 1997)
Cork <- ts(Prices$Cork, start = 1997)
Galway <- ts(Prices$Galway, start = 1997)
Limerick <- ts(Prices$Limerick, start = 1997)
Waterford <- ts(Prices$Waterford, start = 1997)
OtherAreas <- ts(Prices$Other.Areas, start = 1997)
color <- rainbow(ncol(Prices))
ts1 <- ts.plot(National, Dublin, Cork, Galway, Limerick, Waterford, OtherAreas, xlab = "Years", ylab ="Average Price", main = "Second Hand Appartment Prices 1997-2005", col = color)
legend("bottom", legend = colnames(Prices), lty=1, col = color,cex=0.5)
```

I'm trying to change the time series plot so the breaks are e.g 0,50000,100000, etc etc

Can anyone help me on this? Much appreciated

I can only use base R graphics for this as that is specified in the assignment

Here is what my code is producing currently

[Time series plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8jd6.png)

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
ts.plot(National, Dublin, Cork, Galway, Limerick, Waterford, OtherAreas, 
        gpars = list(yaxt = 'n'))
axis(side = 2, 
     at = seq(from = 0, to = max(Prices[, colnames(Prices) != 'Year']), by = 50000), 
     labels = seq(from = 0, to = max(Prices), by = 50000))
```

The argument `yaxt='n'` suppress the ticks on the y-axis.  Then function `axis()` then draw the ticks you want.  You can find more details here: https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html.

Meanwhile, you may want to double check the values of your `ts` objects: Your plot looks interesting in that the y-axis ticks were drawn at values very different from those of your dataset snapshot.

By the way, `Year` is not a time series so you can remove that from the legend.

Comment: The data was sorted in the snapshot so that's probably why it looks off in comparison to the plot.                                                                                                            I tried putting in your code but I'm getting an error saying "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Comment: Just checked again and yeah sorry you are right, the plot is off in relation to the data, do you know how i might fix this?

Comment: I am not sure what went wrong.  You may try the head() function (for example `cbind(fromDF = head(Prices$National), fromTS = head(National);` to just make sure values from the data frame are saved properly into the ts objects.  If, for example, you are working with a long chunk of code, re-running may not be a bad idea since objects might be modified at some moment.